# OpenWrt: LuCI: how to implement limited user access

Tags: authentication, lua, openwrt

Goal: two users root and user. Root can access everything via web-interface, but user should see only some parts of the menus.

One option would be to pass "sysauth" option to every module in question. That is not very practical, because the user would see every menu entry and would get login page for every menu he is not allowed to.

My idea is to figure out who is logged on and then do nothing in the index() function of each restricted module. So far I couldn't find such a function in LuCI API (http://luci.subsignal.org/api/luci/), that would return a current logged user.

I know how to add additional users in OpenWrt/LuCI (https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?pid=163013#p163013). But it is only a part of the solution.

Any idea, how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating a Lua function like described here: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SaveTableToFile, to find and remove unneeded keys from the table.

```
function remove_idx(  tbl, index )

   -- initiate variables for save procedure
   local tables,lookup = { tbl },{ [tbl] = 1 }

   for idx,t in ipairs( tables ) do
      local thandled = {}

      for i,v in ipairs( t ) do
     thandled[i] = true
     local stype = type( v )
     -- only handle value
     if stype == "table" then
        if not lookup[v] then
           table.insert( tables, v )
           lookup[v] = #tables
        end
     else
        if i == index then
           t[i] = nil
           return
        end
     end
      end

      for i,v in pairs( t ) do
     -- escape handled values
     if (not thandled[i]) then

        local flag = 0
        local stype = type( i )
        -- handle index
        if stype == "table" then
           if not lookup[i] then
          table.insert( tables,i )
          lookup[i] = #tables
           end
        else
           flag = 1
           if i == index then
          t[i] = nil
          return
           end
        end

        if flag == 1 then
           stype = type( v )
           -- handle value
           if stype == "table" then
          if not lookup[v] then
             table.insert( tables,v )
             lookup[v] = #tables
          end
           else
          if i == index then
             t[i] = nil
             return
          end
           end
        end

     end
      end
   end
end
```

And then inserted my user check and page delete after in libs/web/luasrc/dispatcher.lua dispatch():

```
if c and c.index then
    local tpl = require "luci.template"

    if util.copcall(tpl.render, "indexer", {}) then
        return true
    end
 end
```

That's how I remove unneeded pages depending on who is logged in:

```
    if ctx.authuser == "user" then
            remove_idx(ctx.tree, "packages")
            remove_idx(ctx.tree, "leds")
    end
```

It is a little bit quick and dirty, but it works. Please note, that direct access by
manipulating the URL is still possible.

**Update**

LuCI2 will provide ACL support und multi-user environment: http://git.openwrt.org/?p=project/luci2/ui.git;a%3Dsummary

Comment: thanks for share your solution.
i have a simple question: i don't know the remove_idx write to which file?
add "user check" after dispatch() function or in dispatch() 'modifi dispatch()'.
and where i use "remove unneeded pages" code?
I'm confused. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: i added `remove_idx` function and user check, but only remove item in menu first page render, if reload or go to other page, `leds` and `packages` item go back and available in menu. may be i bad use check user code, can you help me please?

Comment: Both `remove_idx()` and authentication check must be in `libs/web/luasrc/dispatcher.lua` file, because the whole index tree is built as soon as you open routers web interface. User authentication check must be in the `dispatch()` routine, right after the code I showed in my answer. This is the routine, where the index tree will be filled.

Comment: i added `if ctx.authuser...` after `if c and c.index...`, if i click system or network menu, `leds` and `packages` not available in menu list but if i click `dhcp` or `startup` ..., `leds` and `packages` available in menu list.

Comment: I've solved the problem of reappearing sub-tabs through replacing `c` with `ctx.tree` in `remove_idx()` call. But  direct access by manipulating the URL is still possible.

Comment: thanks, that worked, but i working around making user interface whit `JSONRPC` `luci api` for customer wizard panel.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to create multiple OpenWRT Luci users with varying access, you can following these steps:

1. Create a [local user account](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/security/secure.access)
2. [Add the user to the RCP configuration](https://forum.openwrt.org/t/solved-luci-add-support-user-in-addition-to-root/17402/3) and define access level

See sample excerpt from /etc/config/rpcd config below:

```
config login                     
        option username 'adminuser'
        option password '$p$adminuser'
        list read '*'
        list write '*'
                              
config login                     
        option username 'readonlyuser'
        option password '$p$readonlyuser'
        list read '*'
```

This also works if you're obtaining an authentication token for [JSON-RPC](https://github.com/openwrt/luci/wiki/JsonRpcHowTo) calls to Luci.

Comment: Any idea how to further limit read access e.g. to specific values?